# PHP Markitup wysiwyg doesn't read my content

Tags: php, jquery, wysiwyg, markitup

If i add some text on Markitup wysiwyg, and i send the form, it doesn't save the content of the text area in the POST variable...Someone know why?

```
 `<textarea id="markItUp" cols="80" rows="15" name="contenuto" placeholder="content" required></textarea>`
```

this is the query:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#markItUp').markItUp(mySettings);

// You can add content from anywhere in your page
// $.markItUp( { Settings } );  
$('.add').click(function() {
    $('#markItUp').markItUp('insert',
        {   openWith:'<opening tag>',
            closeWith:'<\/closing tag>',
            placeHolder:"New content"
        }
    );
    return false;
});

// And you can add/remove markItUp! whenever you want
// $(textarea).markItUpRemove();
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    if ($("#markItUp.markItUpEditor").length === 1) {
        $("#markItUp").markItUp('remove');
        $("span", this).text("get markItUp! back");
    } else {
        $('#markItUp').markItUp(mySettings);
        $("span", this).text("remove markItUp!");
    }
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

this is what i include:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="markitup/skins/markitup/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="markitup/sets/default/style.css">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- markItUp! -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="markitup/jquery.markitup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="markitup/sets/default/set.js"></script>
```

Anybody have some ideas?
I pass the variable via POST:

```
...<form action="addnews.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">...
<?php 
$news = new News();
$news->crea($_POST,$image,$userProfile['name']);
 //...
?>
```

and this is the "crea" method of News class:

```
<?php
    public function crea($_POST,$immagine,$autore)
{
    $db = new Database();
    $db->connect();
    $titolo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['titolo']);
    $contenuto = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contenuto']);
    $tags = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tags']);
    $titolo_url = str_replace(

    // Replace these special characters
    array('.',',',':',';','?','!',' ', '<', '>', '&', '\'', '"', '‘', '’', '“', '”', '/', '[', ']','(',')','\'','è','é','à','ò','ù','ì','&igrave;', '&egrave;', '&eacute;', '&ograve;', '&agrave;', '&ugrave;'),

    // With the HTML entities below, respectively
    array('','','','','','','-','-','-','-','-','','','','','','-','-','-','-','-','-','e','e','a','o','u','i','i', 'e', 'e', 'o', 'a', 'u'),

    $titolo);
    $db->insert('news',array('titolo' => ''.$titolo.'','titolo_url' => ''.$titolo_url.'','data' => ''.time().'','contenuto' => ''.$contenuto.'','autore' => ''.$autore.'','tags' => ''.$tags.'','immagine' => ''.$immagine.''));  
    $result = $db->getResult();
    if ($result == true)
        return $result;

}
?>
```

If i don't use Markitup, all rights, but since i've installed it, the "content" don't work.

Comment: where is your `crea` function, you only showed the `modifica`

Comment: i've just edited sorry

Comment: for one thing you don't need to pass `$_POST`